# SignalR Java client only supports exactly 1.3

Tags: java, signalr

Is there a reason why the Java client for SignalR only supports exactly version 1.3?

https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/blob/f226631da562cfaacbe8b16d5a9ecbf8205e7c99/signalr-client-sdk/src/microsoft/aspnet/signalr/client/Connection.java#L597

Shouldn't all clients be backwards compatible? Is there any harm done and changing the `verifyProtocolVersion` method to verify that the protocol is less than or equal to 1.3? For testing purposes, I simply returned true, skipping the entire method body, to see if it worked with my 1.2.1 server, and it did.

Maybe this should be considered a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR protocol versions do not align with SignalR package versions. For example, the SignalR 2.0.* server supports communicating with clients using either version 1.2 or 1.3 of the SignalR protocol:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.0.3/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Infrastructure/ProtocolResolver.cs

It looks like the Java client supports the latest SignalR protocol version as of SignalR 2.0.3.

Comment: I understand this. .NET version libraries aside, shouldn't a client library supporting 1.3 ALSO support 1.2? I understand not being forwards compatible, but no backwards compatibility?

Comment: The SignalR clients released so far have not supported communicating to servers using older versions of the protocol. As noted in my answer, the current server supports the last two protocol versions. 1.2 was the only protocol version supported by SignalR 1.* on both the server and the client. While it would have been nice to make SignalR 2.* clients compatible with 1.* servers, that is not the case. SignalR 1.* clients *are* compatible with 2.* servers. In many cases it's easier to upgrade servers than clients.