# Problems to connect to a SignalR Self-Hosted in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have been trying to connect to the Windows Service created in this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host

The thing is that I do can connect to it using its own client. However, I've tried to connect to it from a console application and haven't had success. Moreover, if I host the SignalR Hub in a console application I can connect to it successfully.

The errors that I got say that my client version isn't compatible with the server and that the connection was refused.

This is how my attempt to connect looks like:

```
 IHubProxy _hub;
 string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
 var connection = new HubConnection(url);
 _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
 _hub.On("addMessage", x => ShowMessage(x));
 connection.Start().Wait();
```

UPDATE:

-Errors Messages:

1.

```
Exception:Caught: "You are using a version of the client that isn't compatible with the server. Client version 1.4, server version 1.3." (System.InvalidOperationException)
A System.InvalidOperationException was caught: "You are using a version of the client that isn't compatible with the server. Client version 1.4, server version 1.3."
Time: 2/20/2015 12:03:36 PM
Thread:Worker Thread[5924]
```

2.

```
Exception:Thrown: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)
A System.Net.Sockets.SocketException was thrown: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"
Time: 2/20/2015 12:03:36 PM
Thread:Worker Thread[3320]
```

Comment: Welcome on SO ! COuld you give us more details about the error message ?

Comment: Thanks!  I've been here for a while but have always find my answers with no need to ask. I've update the description with the message errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SignalR Java client only supports exactly 1.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997568/signalr-java-client-only-supports-exactly-1-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by Christophe, this question is a duplicate of [SignalR Java client only supports exactly 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997568/signalr-java-client-only-supports-exactly-1-3) and, in my case, was solved by uninstalling and re-installing all the SignalR/Owin packages.